# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, groovy, java-time

I have this groovy code which gives me an error and I cannot see why:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.time.DayOfWeek
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters

static String convertDateTimeString(String fromFormat, String toFormat, String dateString) {
    DateTimeFormatter fromFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fromFormat, Locale.GERMAN)
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, fromFormatter)
    DateTimeFormatter toFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(toFormat, Locale.GERMAN)
    localDateTime.format(toFormatter)
}

String date = convertDateTimeString( 'EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z', 'yyyy', "Wed, 04 Feb 2015 10:12:34 UTC")
assert date == '2015'
```

The error ist `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed, 04 Feb 2015 10:12:34 UTC' could not be parsed at index 0`

But I checked the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and everything looks good to me.

Can you tell me what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "Wed", we need to use short weekdays 'So, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa' in German.

```
String date = convertDateTimeString( "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", "yyyy", "Mi, 04 Feb 
2015 10:12:34 UTC");
```

// output 2015

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you set the formatter to parse/format for `Locale.GERMAN` but gave it `"Wed, 04 Feb 2015 10:12:34 UTC"` to parse. `Wed` is for *wednesday* which is english, not german.

To solve the problem, just replace `Locale.GERMAN` by `Locale.ENGLISH`. Another solution would be a parameter for the locale.

Comment: damn, I knew it had to be a tiny stupid mistake... makes sense! Thanks!